# Owl Carousel Enable Window Srcolling

Tags: slider, owl-carousel

When in mobile view using Owl Carousel (Version 2 ) some of my sliders take up near the whole screen.

The carousel uses touch to slide left and right fine however when doing so the user cannot scroll the page up and down which makes it difficult to navigate the to the rest of the page.

Is there a way so that while sliding the scrolling for the page is still active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems i had the touch-action property set to none disabling scrolling and zooming etc when touching on the items within the slide. I had to remove the below although i don't think this is default and i added it in at some point for some reason that i can't remember.

```
.owl-item {
    touch-action: none;
}
```